# Hibernating Win7 - startup starts Xubuntu with error

Tags: grub2, windows, xubuntu, hibernate

on my Dell Vostro 3550 I have Windows 7 and Xubuntu 14.04 installed.

When I hibernate Windows 7 and start the machine the Xubuntu screen is shown telling me about an error about filesystem check of my windows partition.

I can then press S, D or just restart the machine via ctrl+alt+del.

Restart is the only option coming up to grub menu and I have to manually switch to Windows 7 and then it will boot fine up.

Is this a problem about the default boot option of grub or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal behavior. The filesystem driver used to mount NTFS partitions in Ubuntu is 'ntfs-3g' which always expects the NTFS filesystem(s) to be in clean state. Whenever you hibernate Windows 7, by design, Windows always marks all the NTFS partition(s) as dirty. So, next time you boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 in hibernated state, it finds these NTFS partition(s) in dirty state and will complain. It is highly recommended NOT to do an fsck repairs on hibernated NTFS partition(s) in Ubuntu. You can not and should not use an NTFS partition in Linux which was hibernated or even not shutting down the Windows properly will lead to fsck complaints. Always shut down Windows properly before you are going to use the NTFS partition(s) in Ubuntu.

Comment: okay. this helps me to understand the issue and to solve my notebook behaviour. thank you.